# Print out numbers of increasing distance from center value in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to print out numbers by increasing positive and negative values around a center number, and I don't think I've found the best way. For example, say I want to find what number in a list my center value is closest to. I do that by adding one, see if it matches, then subtracting one from the original number and see if that matches, then add two from the original number and so on. I know there are other ways of finding the closest match but I'm not looking for that - I'm looking for the best way to print out numbers steadily getting farther from a center value. Here's my code:

```
def inc_val(center, i, neg_toggle):
    mult = 1
    if neg_toggle:
        neg_toggle = False
        mult = -1
    else:
        neg_toggle = True
        mult = 1
        i += 1
    val = center + (i * mult)
    return val, i, neg_toggle

i = 0
center = 24
val = center
neg_toggle = False
my_set = {30, 50, 90}
while val not in my_set:
    print(val)
    val, i, neg_toggle = inc_val(center, i, neg_toggle)
```

This prints out the following list, as desired:

```
24
25
23
26
22
27
21
28
20
29
19
```

To be clear, I'm interested in the incrementing numbers. The `while not in my_set` part is just to illustrate. I am not intentionally trying to re-invent anything, so if there's a built-in or simpler way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than maintaining the state of the iteration using three variables `val`, `i`, and `neg_toggle`, it would be more elegant to write a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators).  Then, the state of the iteration would be maintained by the flow of the execution of the generator itself.

```
def zoom_out(center):
    decr = center
    incr = center + 1
    while True:
        yield decr
        decr -= 1
        yield incr
        incr += 1

for n in zoom_out(24):
    if n in (30, 50, 90):
        break
    print(n)
```

Furthermore, fancy iteration can often be expressed more elegantly using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).  Here, I'd take advantage of `itertools.count()` to implement the generator, and `itertools.takewhile()` to detect when to stop executing the infinite generator.

```
from itertools import count, takewhile

def zoom_out(center):
    decr = count(center, -1)
    incr = count(center + 1)
    while True:
        yield next(decr)
        yield next(incr)

for n in takewhile(lambda n: n not in (30, 50, 90), zoom_out(24)):
    print(n)
```